# Web Service taking object as parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, web-services, wcf

Basically,

I have a client console using a class I defined called "Part". This class is held in a shared library.

```
    <Serializable()> _
    Public Class Part() 
       Public Property Success As Boolean = False
       Public Property ExportID As Integer = 0
    end class
```

I also have a webservice (Or WCF as I have tried both) that has a method which takes a "Part" object as a parameter. Also taken from the shared library.

```
    objService.AddPart(objPart)
```

However, when I try to invoke this method in the client it keeps erring and telling me that object of type SharedClass.Part cannot be converted to WebSerivce.Part?

```
    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function AddPart(Byval objPart as Part) As Boolean

    End Function
```

I am 99% certain I have missed a step somwhere but for the life of me I can't work it out. The above code was written for illustration purposes so could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In case of WCF, make sure you are decorating "Part" class with "DataContract" & it's properties with "DataMember" attribute. For Web service, I don't think you need to make anything extra.

Here's a sample webservice,

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebServiceWithJson
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class SayHelloService 
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string GreetingsWithObj(SayHelloDto ObjSayHelloDto)
        {
            return ObjSayHelloDto.Greeting + " " + ObjSayHelloDto.Name;
        }
    }
    public class SayHelloDto
    {
        public string Greeting { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

add reference and this is how you can consume,

```
using System;
using SayHelloSvcConsumer.SayHelloServiceReference;
namespace SayHelloSvcConsumer
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ObjSayHelloService = new SayHelloServiceSoapClient();
            var ObjSayHelloDto = new SayHelloDto
                {
                    Greeting = "Hello",
                    Name = "Rasmita"
                };
            var GreetingMsg = ObjSayHelloService.GreetingsWithObj(ObjSayHelloDto);
            Response.Write(GreetingMsg);
        }
    }
}
```

Will be better if you can post some sample code of any service.
Hope it will help